# Checking if message has content from a .txt in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanna detect if a message contains a word from a .txt, with basic arrays is really simple, but i can't figure out how to apply it to files, i tried converting the txt into an array and checking for the array, code here:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8')
const fileToArray = file.split('\n')

        if (fileToArray.includes(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send("test")then(msg => {
                setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3500)
            })
```

also tried with using .some instead of .includes but nothing, hope you can help

Comment: Firstly, `Array.prototype.includes` does not accept a function as its first parameter. Secondly, are you getting any errors/problems? What are they?

Comment: it doesn't crash or gives any error, it just doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean nothing happens? It just doesn’t run basically?

Comment: the code should delete the message, but it doesn't, and it doesn't give errors

Comment: It’s probably because the `Array.prototype.includes` doesn’t return true

Comment: how can i fix that then?

Comment: either change it to `.some` or change the parameter to a word/phrase/regex you want to look for

Answer (score 0):

It looks an awful lot like you're trying to do text filtering. Let me show you how I did it.

The first thing you want to do is bring in the file as lines. They get inserted into an array. Then I set "confirm" false, because I want to just use a boolean value that I can check outside of the "for" loop.

All of your file gets read into "wordList" as individual lines, and we're splitting them all on \n, which gives you an array that looks like [word,word2,word3] etc.

Then we do a forEach loop through every word in the message, to see if it contains any words from our array. We add a safety return if word === "" Because different OS handle carriage returns differently, and we don't want it deleting messages for having empty space in them.

Lastly we set confirm to true when a word is found, which takes us out of the loop, and down to the if(confirm), which when true, will delete the message and send a response.

```
                const readFileLines = filename =>
                    fs
                    .readFileSync(filename)
                    .toString('UTF8')
                    .split('\n');
                const wordList = readFileLines('filter.txt');

                let confirm = false;


                wordList.forEach((word) => {
                if(message.content.includes(word)){
                    if(word === "") return;
                            confirm = true;
                            return;
                    }
                })

            if(confirm){
                message.delete();
                message.channel.send("That language is not permitted here.")
            }
```